# Task scheduler Windows 7(schtasks) set Principals RunLevel highest returns Access denied (Run with highest privilege)?

Tags: windows, python, administrator, cmd.exe, task-scheduler

SCHTASKS /Create /TN "New Task" /SC HOURLY /TR blah.exe /RU myusername /RP pypassword /RL HIGHEST

Returns `{ERROR: Access Denied}` Error
also used below code in Xml but still getting the same Error `{ERROR: Access Denied}`

`<Principals> 
  <Principal id="Author">
    <UserId>SYSTEM</UserId>
    <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
  </Principal>
</Principals>`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer that helped me, if i ran my tool as an administrator which is made in QtPY or run cmd as an administrator it executes this command correctly sets Highest privilege but still looking for a better way then RUN AS ADMIN –  Muhammad Furqan